# Trying to understand definable set definition

Tags: logic, model-theory

I recently stumbled upon the definition of a definable set. Wikipedia says:

For $\mathcal{L}$ a first order language, $\mathcal{M}$ an $\mathcal{L}$ structure with domain $M$, $X \subset M$ fixed subset, $m \in \mathbb{N}$ call a set $A \subset M^m$ definable in $\mathcal{M}$ if there is a formula $\phi[x_1, \dots, x_m, y_1, \dots, y_n]$ and there are $b_1,\dots, b_n \in X$ s.t. for every $a_1,\dots, a_m \in M$:
$$ (a_1,\dots,a_m) \in A \iff \mathcal{M} \models \phi[a_1,\dots,a_m,b_1,\dots, b_n]. $$

If $X = \emptyset$ one speaks of definability without parameters. An element $a \in M$ is definable in $\mathcal{M}$ if $\{a\}$ is.

---

My questions are best stated by using the following example:

I've read that in the case of $Z := (\mathbb{Z},+)$ it holds that no element except $0$ is definable in that structure. This can be shown by employing the result that definability of sets is invariant under automorphisms, and $x \mapsto -x$ is an automorphism on $\mathbb{Z}$. So the only preserved set would be $A = \{ a \in \mathbb{Z} : Z \models a + a = a \} = \{ 0 \}$.

1. Working with the definition only, what is the problem with the attempt to show that $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ is definable in $Z$ by employing the formula $\phi(x)$ given by $x + 0 = 1 $ with parameters in $\{ 0,1 \}$? Where does the definition break down?
2. Is the definition of definability without parameters more interesting to people in general? (is the usage of parameters somehow considered as "cheap"?)

Comment: What your quote from Wikipedia calls "definable" would usually be called "definable with parameters from $X$."

Comment: If parameters are allowed then every element $a$ would be definable by just taking $x=a$. Usually "definable" means "definable without parameters", although it can be interesting to look at definability-with-parameters for infinite sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In more detail than my comment: There are three unambiguous expressions and one ambiguous one. The unambiguous ones are "definable with parameters from $X$" (which means what you quoted from Wikipedia), "definable with parameters" (the special case where $X$ is all of $\mathcal M$), and "definable without parameters" (the special case where $X$ is empty). The ambiguous one is "definable", which I've previously seen for the second and for the third of the unambiguous versions, and which your Wikipedia quote uses for the first.  Since "definable" is shorter than the  others, people often use it as an abbreviation for one of the others, but they should say which one.

Comment: +1. And to the OP's specific questions: (1) $1$ is indeed definable with parameters from $\{0,1\}$ (or even just $\{1\}$), but this is pretty boring since for every structure $\mathcal{M}$ and every element $m\in\mathcal{M}$ we have that $m$ is definable in $\mathcal{M}$ with parameters from $\{m\}$. (2) See the second half of the answer to (1) - parameters don't always cheapen things and often definability with arbitrary parameters results in a nicer overal notion of definability, but if we're paying attention to the complexity of individual elements then we *really* want to avoid parameters.